# How to match part of a specific column's values from a dynamic array in Azure Log Analytics query?

Tags: azure, join, logging, smtp, azure-log-analytics

We currently have two queries to do this specific job but I'm trying to merge it into one query.

First query - Used the get the message ID of SMTP logs:

```
Syslog
| where Timegenerated > ago(1d)
| where Computer contains "smtpserver"
| where SyslogMessage contains "to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>"
| project EventTime, Computer, SyslogMessage
```

Result for that will be like:

```
smtpserver01 | 2019-08-13T13:00:14.000 | xXXXX123456: to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>,<jsmith@mycompany.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=658974, relay=pp1235.fortimail.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred

smtpserver02 | 2019-08-13T22:23:52.000 | xXXXX123456: to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=654715, relay=pp1235.fortimail.com. [1xx.2xx.1xx.1xx], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (xXXXX123456-xXXXX123456 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Second Query - get the transactions for that message ID

From there, I take the MessageID (xXXXX123456) and throw that into another similar query to view transactions for that specific MessageID.

```
let msgID = "xXXXX123456";
Syslog
| where Computer contains "smtpserver"
| where SyslogMessage contains msgID
| project EventTime, Computer, HostIP, SyslogMessage
```

This displays about five or six rows for one message ID. First row is Subject info, second row is Sender info, etc.

Thus, I'm trying to merge these two into one single query and here are the two approaches I've tried so far:

```
//Create a dynamic array of unique message IDs from first query
let msgIDs = Syslog
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Computer contains "smtpserver"
| where SyslogMessage contains "to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>"
| project msgId=substring(SyslogMessage,0,14) //first 13 characters of SyslogMessage is the message ID
| distinct msgId;
Syslog
| where SyslogMessage contains (msgIDs)
//| where SyslogMessage has (msgIDs)
| project EventTime, Computer, HostIP, SyslogMessage
```

`contains` or `has` doesn't work because I'm trying to match a list with technically another list. Second option was to use Join() operator but I have no idea what I'm doing with it due to the substring splitting. Here's what I have so far:

```
Syslog
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Computer contains "smtpserver"
| project format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'), msgID=substring(SyslogMessage,0,14) 
| join kind= inner (
    Syslog
    | where Computer contains "smtpserver"
    | where SyslogMessage contains "to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>"
    // Match SyslogMessage here with msgID from above but has or contains doesn't work. How to do that?
    | project msgID=substring(SyslogMessage,0,14), SyslogMessage
) on msgID
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your first solution. And if the returned msgIDs is list, please use `in` operator instead of `contains/has` operators.

Change your first solution as blow:

```
//Create a dynamic array of unique message IDs from first query
let msgIDs = Syslog
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Computer contains "smtpserver"
| where SyslogMessage contains "to=<jdoe@mycompany.com>"
| project msgId=substring(SyslogMessage,0,14) //first 13 characters of SyslogMessage is the message ID
| distinct msgId;
Syslog
//Here, use the in operator
| where SyslogMessage in (msgIDs)
| project EventTime, Computer, HostIP, SyslogMessage
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan Yang. "in" worked. However, I had to this:
```| where id=substring(SyslogMessage,0,14) in (msgIDs)```